# Unpacking a vector into an array of a certain bit width

Tags: system-verilog

Suppose I have a vector of bits. I'd like to convert it into an array of *n* bit values, where *n* is a variable (not a parameter). Can I achieve this using the streaming operators? I tried this (right now I'm just trying a value of 3, but eventually '3' should be variable):

```
module tb;
  bit [51:0] vector = 'b111_110_101_100_011_010_001_000;
  byte vector_byte[];
  
  initial begin
    $displayb(vector);
    vector_byte = {<<3{vector}};
    foreach(vector_byte[i])
      $display("%0d = %0b", i, vector_byte[i]);
  end
endmodule
```

What I was expecting was:

```
vector_byte = '{'b000, 'b001, 'b010 ... 'b111};
```

However, the output I got was:

```
# vsim -voptargs=+acc=npr
# run -all
# 00000000000000000000000000000000111110101100011010001000
# 0 = 101
# 1 = 111001
# 2 = 1110111
# 3 = 0
# 4 = 0
# 5 = 0
# 6 = 0
# exit
```

Am I just using the streaming operators wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The streaming operators only work with contiguous streams. You need 5'b00000 inserted into each byte.

```
module tb;
  bit [51:0] vector = 'b111_110_101_100_011_010_001_000;
  int W = 3;
  byte vector_byte[];
  
  initial begin
    vector_byte = new[$bits(vector)/3];
    $displayb(vector);
    foreach(vector_byte[i]) begin
      vector_byte[i] = vector[i*W+:8] & (1<<W)-1; // mask W is in range 1-8
      $display("%0d = %0b", i, vector_byte[i]);
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks @dave_59. I figured this would be the only solution. As I mentioned, the '3' part comes from a variable, and part-slicing requires a constant for the slice. Am I right in assuming I have to assemble each element myself with another 'for' loop?

Comment: You don't need another for loop if the variable is between 1 and 8 as I've shown in my edited answer. For more than 8 bits, then yes you'll need another for a loop.